# how to add maxlength for TextAreaFor in View using razor engine

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a TextArea() control in my View implemented using Razor Engine.

```
@Html.TextArea("EventNature",new { style = "width: 200px; height: 100px;" })
```

How can i set the Maxlength attribute for this control?
is there any built in Attribute in RazorEngine or do i have to use scripts?

Comment: Note that you don't use `TextAreaFor` in your question...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
@Html.TextArea("EventNature",new { maxlength=50, // or other value
                                  style = "width: 200px; height: 100px;" })
```

Just be aware it's an HTML5 attribute

> maxlength **HTML5**
>   The maximum number of characters (Unicode code points) that the user can enter. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea)

---

Javascript(using jQuery) validation for HTML <5:

```
$('#EventNature').keypress(function(){
    if (this.value.length >= 10) // allowing you to enter only 10 chars.
    return false;        
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/35WAV/)

Comment: Thnx... any way i've to use Javascript for the validation when it comes to HTML5 incompatible browsers rite?

Comment: any link where i can follow-up for the javascript validation, coz i haven't used Js with Razor ;)

Comment: @Kamil. Didn't get your question.

Comment: @Kamil. Just the way you did. But you better use [`TextAreaFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703546.aspx)

Comment: The script doesn't work when you copy/paste text into the TextArea

Comment: @MCollard use same code, replace\add `keypress` with `mouseup` event.

Answer (score 7):

This also works for the **TextAreaFor** helper with more than one anonymous type in `new`

**Confirmed** to **work fine** in **Visual Studio 2015** with **MVC 5**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, 5, 500, new {maxlength=4000,  @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also restrict the length of textbox, like this:

```
<textarea id="EventNature1" maxlength="10"></textarea>

        OR
@Html.TexareaFor(m=>m.Name,new{@maxlength="10"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Customer Number: @Html.TextBox("SearchString1",null, new {maxlength = 6})
 <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
```

The above is an example that worked for me to restrict the maximum allowed characters to be entered.  The tips that show up that you can arrow through when using a .Net environment are extremely helpful. (*note, this doesn't physically change the size of the text box)

"SearchString1" = String name  ----- null = Object value ------ new {maxlength = 6} = object htmlAttributes

Answer (score -1):

> How can i set the Maxlength attribute for this control?

The `maxlength` attribute is not valid for the `<textarea>` element. That's not an ASP.NET MVC limitation. In the HTML specification this attribute is defined only for simple text input fields. If you want to limit the number of characters that a user could type in a textarea you could use javascript.

Comment: It's not true. maxlength is an HTML5 attribute.

Comment: This is an extremely old answer, and I don't use this website anymore. But I was pointed to it again, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength